# tf.gradients: ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I need to get the gradient of weights and biases with tf.gradients():

```
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, x_train.shape[1]])
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, y_train.shape[1]])
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, y_train.shape[1]])

        Wx=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(stddev=0.1,shape=[x_train.shape[1],n_hidden]))
        Wy=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(stddev=0.1,shape=[y_train.shape[1],n_hidden]))
        b=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[n_hidden]))

        hidden_joint=tf.nn.relu((tf.matmul(x,Wx)+tf.matmul(y,Wy))+b)
        hidden_marg=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,Wx)+tf.matmul(y_,Wy)+b)

        Wout=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(stddev=0.1,shape=[n_hidden, 1]))
        bout=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[1]))

        out_joint=tf.matmul(hidden_joint,Wout)+bout
        out_marg=tf.matmul(hidden_marg,Wout)+bout

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.005)


        t = out_joint
        et = tf.exp(out_marg)

        ex_delta_t = tf.reduce_mean(tf.gradients(t, tf.trainable_variables()))
        ex_delta_et = tf.reduce_mean(tf.gradients(et, tf.trainable_variables()))
```

But I always get the following error:

```
  File "/home/ferdi/Documents/mine/mine.py", line 77, in get_mi_batched
    ex_delta_t = tf.reduce_mean(tf.gradients(t, tf.trainable_variables()))
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1490, in reduce_mean
    reduction_indices),
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1272, in _ReductionDims
    return range(0, array_ops.rank(x))
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 368, in rank
    return rank_internal(input, name, optimize=True)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 388, in rank_internal
    input_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(input)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1048, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1144, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 971, in _autopacking_conversion_function
    return _autopacking_helper(v, dtype, name or "packed")
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 923, in _autopacking_helper
    return gen_array_ops.pack(elems_as_tensors, name=scope)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4689, in pack
    "Pack", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3272, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1790, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "/home/ferdi/anaconda3/envs/ml_all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1629, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 3 with other shapes. for 'Rank/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [512,20], [10,20], [20], [20,1], [1].
```

If I reshape or do similar things, there are other error occurring. I know that there are many similar question but I still couldn't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found the solution, please read my up-to-date answer below.

Comment: Did you see my answer, what is the developments, cause I found the issue quite interesting.

Comment: thanks geeocode, you're a star!

Comment: I really happy, that it worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution:**

```
ex_delta_t = tf.reduce_mean( tf.concat([tf.reshape(g, [-1]) for g in tf.gradients(t, tf.trainable_variables())], axis=0))
ex_delta_et = tf.reduce_mean( tf.concat([tf.reshape(g, [-1]) for g in tf.gradients(et, tf.trainable_variables())], axis=0))
```

**Or the same code unfolded:**

```
grads_t_0 = tf.gradients(t, tf.trainable_variables())
grads_et_0 = tf.gradients(t, tf.trainable_variables())

grads_t = []
grads_et = []
for gt,get in zip(grads_t_0, grads_et_0):
    grads_t.append(tf.reshape(gt, [-1]))
    grads_et.append(tf.reshape(get, [-1]))

grads_t_flatten = tf.concat(grads_t, axis=0)
grads_et_flatten = tf.concat(grads_et, axis=0)

ex_delta_t = tf.reduce_mean(grads_t_flatten)
ex_delta_et = tf.reduce_mean(grads_et_flatten)
```

**Explanation:**

You may get this error message, because your gradient functions

```
tf.gradients(t, tf.trainable_variables())
tf.gradients(et, tf.trainable_variables()
```

returns multiply shaped tensors.
As a result your `tf.reduce_mean()` operation complains, that it can't work with this multiply shaped tensors.

As a possibility to workaround this, you should first flatten than concatenate the gradient list, then pass it to the reduce_mean function.

> **Let's see a simple example code to simulate the error and its solution!**

```
#You dummy gradients as the output of tf.gradients()
grad_wx = tf.constant(0.1, shape=[512, 20])
grad_wy = tf.constant(0.2, shape=[10, 20])
grad_b = tf.constant(0.3, shape=[20])
grad_wout = tf.constant(0.4, shape=[20, 1])
grad_bout = tf.constant(0.5, shape=[1])

grads_0 = [grad_wx, grad_wy, grad_b, grad_wout, grad_bout]

sess = tf.Session()

result = tf.reduce_mean(grads_0)
print(sess.run(result)
```

**Out(error):**

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 3 with other shapes. for 'Rank/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [512,20], [10,20], [20], [20,1], [1].
```

**Solution:**

```
result = tf.reduce_mean( tf.concat([tf.reshape(g, [-1]) for g in grads_0], axis=0))
print(sess.run(result))
```

**Out(fixed):**

```
0.102899365
```

Comment: what do you mean by y has only 1 dim? y has shape (n, 10) and x (n, 512). They are then mapped to hidden_joint and hidden_marg which have shape (n, n_hidden).

Comment: @FerdiK Then you have to provide more information us to be able to answer, like shape of x,y and other tensors, some data and label sample etc.

Comment: Ok sure, thanks! x.shape = (300, 512), y.shape = (300, 10). y is the one hot enc. of 10 classes. x entries are between 0 and 1, e.g. [0.00376076 0.6290544  0.         ... 0.44217262 0.         0.53888565]. n_hidden = 20, so Wx.shape = (512, 20), Wy.shape = (10, 20) and Wout.shape = (20,1). Why does it complain about merging shape 3 with other shapes? It shouldn't matter, that the biases are only 1D arrays and weights 2D arrays. If I reshape the biases to [1, 20] and [1,1], it complains: ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 20 and 1. Shapes are [20,1] and [1,1].

Comment: @FerdiK There are some initializations some gradients weights and biasses, but what is the purpose of `(tf.matmul(x,Wx)+tf.matmul(y,Wy)`, why we use the labels here to any computation?

Comment: sorry, y aren't the labels: The net is an implementation of MINE (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04062.pdf). The network tries to give a lower bound to the mutual information between x and y. It doesn't train on labeled data, it tries to maximzie the following objective: lower_bound = t  - tf.log(et), where t is the 1-dim outputs of the net. And et = exp(t)

Comment: Specifically in that context, I have the following problem: When training the network with mini-batches, one needs to correct the gradients of the mini-batches to be representative of the whole data. (Section 3.2 of the paper). That's why I need to obtain the gradients, make the correction and then apply the corrected gradients to the net's parameters.

Comment: @FerdiK Still ambiguous, but I have a guess, that you get too much tf.trainable_variables(), I mean are you sure that all of your Variable() have to be trainable?

Comment: Yes I am. Its the two weight matrices for the hidden layer, the bias of the hidden layer and the weight matrix and bias for the output layer. I'm not sure if tf struggles that there are 2 weight matrices for the hidden layer. I will try to just concatenate when I get home. I'll let you know how that worked!

Comment: @FerdiK Any development?

Comment: Yes, I've just used the optimizer's calculate_gradients() and it worked. (not 100% if I didn't also change something else). I still don't really get what the problem was though ...